# CODESYS safety programming: SIL2 package and PLCopen specification

Tags: codesys

I ask here a question about the PLCopen specification over Codesys SIL2 package. I've already asked this on Codesys Forge Fourm, without reply. It seems that on that forum no-one reply to safety questions.

Reading the Codesys SIL2 user manual I can't understand the worth of the PLCopen specification. I report from the manual:

Chapter 1.3: "Aderence to the safety requirements listed in Appendix 7.4 is absolutely necessary."

Safety requiment 3-4.5 (from appendix 7.4): "The permitted programming languages for the programming of a Codesys Safety SIL2 controller are listed in chapter 5."

Chapter 5 (about programming): "...The rules are only raccommendations that enable the certification to be simplified...".

Chapter 5 reports almost all the PLCopen specification, with some little differences. So, I can't understand if it's necessary to use the "chapter 5 rules" to program SIL2 ECU or if those allow a simpler certification of the system.

Someone has ever stucked with this issue?

Thanks,
Francesco

Comment: Hi Francesco... This is a very technical question, I believe the most likely place to find someone who really knows this would be on the Codesys forum... As no one has answered you yet, I would recommend contacting codesys support directly.

Comment: Hi dwpessoa, thanks for the reply! I thought that someone had the same problem, so I asked. The strange thing is that also Codesys don't know the reply! I'm searching for answer, when I will find something I will post on this thread.